# How to choose what feature vector to plot in multivariate regression analysis?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-distribution

I'm new to the field of machine learning and I have been having this doubt for a long time now. If we want to plot a scatter plot, we plot it as, x as a function of y where x is a 1-D array. But in the case of multivariate regression, we have so many choices to plot X from, how does one choose which feature vector is to be plotted in the scatter plot?

As for why I want to plot it, it's to visually confirm that my model fits the data.

Thank you in advance!!! 
have a good day :D

Comment: Because "multivariate regression" concerns more than one *response,* I have removed that tag.  I also removed the polynomial tag because your question (as stated) has nothing to do with polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot all the possible pairs of scatter plots. There are $n(n-1)/2$ of them, where $n$ is the number of features. It can be useful for data analysis as well. There's no rule as to which one to choose without having a specific/domain knowledge or having calculated the features importance.

If $n$ is too large, and all features are equally important, then plotting a sample can be a bit informative but inconclusive.

Comment: Hello xi45, sorry for the late reply. In my case n = 26 (without one hot encoding) so I think  plotting all the features would take a toll on my pc. Also, what do you mean by "importance"can you please explain? And another thing as for the 'sample'you told me about what I did was find correlations of each independent variable with each other and the dependent variable. By importance do you perhaps mean that the independent variable that correlates to the dependent variable the most should be plotted.I should look for the independent variable that when correlated to the dependent has max(coeff)

Comment: In this case your $n$ is the total number of independent features. By importance I simply meant the ones contributing most to your result (you can know that from domain knowledge or feature importance analysis) so that you visually check your result for the most relevant features (<<26) instead of plotting everything.